# Can I add an 'environment variable' in CMake GUI Wizard?

Tags: cmake

A CMake script I am using expects an environment variable XXX_HOME to be set, but I don't have this and don't want to add it.

Is there a way to trick CMake into thinking this variable exists, with a value I set, in the CMake cache - ideally using the CMake GUI - so I don't have to edit the CMake scripts? I tried adding a setting in the GUI `XXX_HOME = ...` but it didn't work.

Comment: Can't you run cmake-gui from an environment with the environment variable set. I do this all the time on windows so that I can build for different compilers / different bit depths in totally different build trees with the same source. In linux you also should be able to set the variable on the same line as cmake-gui. Like this XXX_HOME="/usr/src/xxx" cmake-gui

Comment: hmm, perhaps I can. Worth a try.

Comment: @drescherjm if you want the green tick move that to an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you run cmake-gui from an environment with the environment variable set? I do this all the time on windows using batch files and shortcuts to the visual studio command prompt so that I can build for different compilers / different bit depths in totally different build trees with the same source.

In linux you also should be able to set the variable on the same line as cmake-gui. Like this XXX_HOME="/usr/src/xxx" cmake-gui

Comment: This answer isn't aligned with the spirit of a GUI. But anyway @Mr. Boy where's that tick you promsed!?